# F# type provider - "only return generated types"

Tags: f#, type-providers

Trying to encode type-level peano numbers using a type provider:

```
namespace TypeProviderPlayground

open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<assembly: TypeProviderAssembly()>]
do()

type Z = class end
type 'a S = class end
type N = class end

[<TypeProvider>]
type PeanoProvider(s: TypeProviderConfig) =
    let invalidate = Event<_,_>()
    interface ITypeProvider with
        member x.ApplyStaticArguments(typeWithoutArguments, typeNameWithArguments, staticArguments) =
            let n : int = unbox staticArguments.[0]
            [1..n] |> List.fold (fun s _ -> typedefof<S<_>>.MakeGenericType [| s |]) typeof<Z>
        member x.GetNamespaces() = 
            let ns = 
                { new IProvidedNamespace with
                    member x.GetNestedNamespaces() = [||]
                    member x.GetTypes() = [||]
                    member x.ResolveTypeName t =
                        if t = "N"
                            then typeof<N>
                            else null
                    member x.NamespaceName = "Peano" }
            [| ns |]
        member x.GetStaticParameters t =
            let p = 
                { new Reflection.ParameterInfo() with
                    member z.Name = "number"
                    member z.ParameterType = typeof<int> }
            [| p |]

        [<CLIEvent>]
        member x.Invalidate = invalidate.Publish
        member x.Dispose() = ()
        member x.GetInvokerExpression(syntheticMethodBase, parameters) = 
            raise <| NotImplementedException()
```

The `N` type is just a dummy, otherwise I couldn't get it to go through the type provider.
Consumer code:

```
open TypeProviderPlayground

[<Generate>]
type S<'a> = Peano.N<5>
```

And I get this error:

```
error FS3152: The provider 'TypeProviderPlayground.PeanoProvider' returned a non-generated type
'TypeProviderPlayground.S`1[[TypeProviderPlayground.S`1[[TypeProviderPlayground.S`1[[TypeProviderPlayground.S`1[[TypeProviderPlayground.S`1[[TypeProviderPlayground.Z, TypeProviderPlayground, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], TypeProviderPlayground, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], TypeProviderPlayground, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], TypeProviderPlayground, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], TypeProviderPlayground, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' 
in the context of a [<Generate>] declaration. Either remove the [<Generate>] declaration or adjust the type provider to only return generated types.
```

Which says that the type was correctly constructed (`Z S S S S S`) but for some reason the compiler won't accept it as a "generated type".

If I remove the `[<Generated>]` attribute I get some other error telling me to add it.

Does this mean that type providers will only work on dynamically emitted types (which seems a weird requirement at first blush)?

Also, if I do:

```
[<Generate>]
type WW<'a> = Peano.N<5>
```

I get an error saying that `WW'1` was expected but `S'1` was returned. Why does the returned type (by the type provider) have to match the type name I declare in the consumer?

Comment: IIRC from Don's presentation at //build, the example of custom type provider he used inherited from a type, rather than implementing the interface. That might be easier to use, for instance it might provide boiler-plate code that works for the parts of the interface that are unclear (GetInvokerExpression)

Comment: If you look at 50:49 in the video, you will see that SampleTypeProvider inherits from TypeProviderForNamespaces. This class hasn't been released yet. See also http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2011/09/18/first-example-of-a-very-simple-type-provider.aspx if you can't wait, it seems Robert has figured out how to fill in some of the holes.

Comment: @Joh: I don't think GetInvokerExpression applies to my example.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/09/24/developing-f-type-providers-with-the-f-3-0-developer-preview-an-introductory-guide-and-samples.aspx may be of interest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few important things to realize about type providers.  First of all, there are two kinds of provided types:

1. *Generated types*  are real .NET types that get embedded into the assembly that uses the type provider (this is what the type providers that wrap code generation tools like sqlmetal use)
2. *Erased types* are simulated types which are represented by some other type when the code is compiled.

Just as a heads-up, the mechanisms for controlling this distinction are still somewhat up in the air.  In the preview, you need to use the `[<Generate>]` attribute in the assembly into which generated types are being embedded, and you should not use the `[<Generate>]` attribute when using an erased provided type.  I believe (but can't remember for sure off hand) that on the provided end generated-ness is determined based on the type's `Assembly` property.

Also, keep in mind that you don't necessarily want to use actual types (e.g. via `typeof<X>`) when implementing the API - you'll frequently want to use custom types derived from `System.Type`.  There are a lot of invariants that must be satisfied among the different methods.  The raw type provider API is not easy to use - I'd suggest waiting for some examples to be released which use a nicer API wrapper (which I hope should take place within the next few weeks).

Having said that, from a quick look here are at least a few things in your current approach which look wrong to me:

1. The type that you're returning from `ApplyStaticArguments` doesn't have the same name as the argument `typeNameWithArguments`.  Presumably this is why you're getting the error mentioning the type names.
2. You're trying to use a type abbreviation which creates a generic type (e.g. `WW<'a>`) from a non-generic type (e.g. `S<S<S<S<S<Z>>>>>`).

Comment: Thanks! +1 About the first comment, why does the generated type name have to match the consumer type name? It seems rather odd for the type generator to have to know about the consumer's type name. About your second suggestion, I did try first to bind to a non-generic type and I got the same error about mismatched type names (`S` vs `S'1`).

Comment: I know I have no idea about the invariants you mention that the types must satisfy... but I think the API would be much easier to use if it could just work with regular types (as in `typeof<X>`)

Comment: @Mauricio - Uses of generated types are very different from normal type abbreviations, in that they define where a real .NET type should be embedded.  Therefore, if you have a definition like `[<Generate>]type T = ...`, the resulting assembly will really contain a type T, and the type provider infrastructure expects the provider to generate such a type accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but still it doesn't work. Is it even possible to implement what I'm trying to do or should I just give up?

Comment: @Mauricio - well, it would be helpful for you to elaborate on exactly what you're trying to do...  What code do you expect users of your type provider to write, and what do you want that to compile to?

Comment: `N<5>` should compile to `Z S S S S S`

Comment: @Mauricio - In that case you want an erasing type provider, which will be hard to create without using a more friendly wrapper over the raw API.

Answer (score 4):

Forgot to update on this: indeed what was missing was the 'erased' type flag (`TypeProviderTypeAttributes.IsErased`) in my 'exported' type. I put my [experiments on github](https://github.com/mausch/TypeProviderPlayground).