# F# type providers with Portable Library

Tags: f#, windows-runtime, type-providers

I'm building a Windows 8 application and am finding myself wanting to include a list of [ISO-4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) codes, which I have in up-to-date form in XML.

Naturally, there are a couple of these codes for all countries. I figured a Type Provider would be an excellent fit. However, since they emit code, I can't use them with Portable Libraries.

How do I compile the type provider so that it doesn't use emit, in order to use the [XML I've got](http://www.currency-iso.org/dl_iso_table_a1.xml)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have experience with creating a Type Provider that is useable from Portable Libraries, but you seem to be assuming that type providers emit code *at runtime*. This is not actually true and so using them in Portable setting might be easier.

The type provider is executed when you run the F# compiler. At this point, it *may* generate some types, although only one kind of type providers actually does that (there are two different kinds - see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118866/how-do-i-create-an-f-type-provider-that-can-be-used-from-c)). However, when you compile code that uses an F# type provider, the resulting assembly does not emit any code at runtime.

I think the [Freebase type provider](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/tree/master/src) (available in FSharpX) is an example of a provider that works in Portable mode. I suspect that a part of the trick is to split the provider into two assemblies - one that contains code that is needed *at runtime* and another that contains *design time* components (which build type information, although they also do not need emit). See `TypeProviderAssembly` attribute in [FreebaseRuntime.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.TypeProviders.Freebase/FreebaseRuntime.fs).

Comment: OK, it's great it's possible, but *how* is it done - I have no interest in creating a type provider, but thought XML would be an obvious target for an existing provider.

Comment: @Henrik - Here's a [type provider for XML documents](https://nuget.org/packages/FSharpx.TypeProviders.Documents). Not sure whether it works in a portable library, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

[XmlProvider from FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html) works with portable libraries