# Seq.map from one list to populate another list of different type?

Tags: f#, mapping, sequence

This question is in follow up to an earlier question, [Preserving Field names across the F#/C# boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963487/preserving-field-names-across-the-f-c-boundary?noredirect=1#comment33295940_21963487)

Because of the current limitation encountered with F# type providers (see the earlier question), I want to map the type-provider-generated list to my own list of records, in which the record is, in part,

```
type inspection = {
    inspectionID : string;
    inspectorID : int;
    EstablishmentID : string;
    EstablishmentName : string;  // other members elided
}
```

I think the way to do this will use Seq.map, but I am not certain.  (Recall I am doing a learning exercise.)  So here is what I tried:

```
type restaurantCsv = CsvProvider<"C:\somepath\RestaurantRatings2013.csv",HasHeaders=true> 
// which generates a type, but it is an "erased" type, so member names do not propogate
//    over to C#.

type RawInspectionData(filename : string) = 
    member this.allData = restaurantCsv.Load(filename)  // works fine

    member this.allInspections = 
        this.allData.Data
            |> Seq.map(fun rcrd -> new inspection[{inspectionID = rcrd.InspectionID;}])
```

and, of course, the complete statement would have the other member names as part of the inspection, here elided for brevity.  Someone pointed me to p 43 of *F# For Scientists*, which is why I thought to use this format with the curly braces.  But this yields a syntax error, "Unexpected symbol '{' in expression. Expected ',', ']' or other token."

Hopefully, though, this snippet is adequate to show what I would like to do, create a Generated Type from the Erased Type.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is going in the right direction. When using `Seq.map` (which is like `Select` in LINQ), you need to turn a single element of the original sequence into a single element of the new sequence. So the lambda function just needs to create a single instance of the record.

A record is constructed using `{ Field1 = value1; Field2 = value2; ... }` so you need:

```
type RawInspectionData(filename : string) = 
  let allData = restaurantCsv.Load(filename)  // works fine
  member this.allInspections = 
    allData.Data
    |> Seq.map(fun rcrd -> {inspectionID = rcrd.InspectionID})
```

I also changed `allData` from a member to a local `let` definition (which makes it private field of the class). I suppose that your original code `new inspection[{...}]` tried to create a singleton array with the element - to create an array you'd write `[| { Field = value; ... } |]` (and the compiler would infer the type of the array for you). But in this case, no arrays are needed.

Comment: On the final line of code, my final working syntax is a little different from what you suggest:  |> Seq.map(fun rcrd ->                 {inspection.inspectionID = rcrd.InspectionID;  That is, it would not compile until I added the type name to inspectionID.  But /it works/.  Thank you very much Tomas.  By the way, I hope you get to come to Raleigh, NC, US some day.  A lot of folks here would be very interested to see you present.